# Bash: nest variable within variable problem

Tags: bash

I'm working on the beginning of a script to navigate from `home/user/` to `home/user/public_html/domain`

Since there are quite a few different domains I want to design a script where the first step lands me in the right directory before continuing on with more commands.

So far I've got

```
$ cat executablefile.txt

domaincom=example.com 
domain=$(echo ${domaincom/.com})
step1=$(cd public_html/$domain) 
     
echo $step1

pwd
```

and I run a `sed` command to replace example.com with my domain but I still get

```
home/user/
```

as the output.

I've tried not using `echo` at the end and adding `;` on the end of each line to separate the variables but I know I'm messing up nesting the variable `$domain` into `$step1`. I've tried using ``` {``} ``` around `$domain` and still cant get this script to turn the way I want. I need the top 2 variables for more commands later in the script where I do or don't need the .com on the end but have tried it also with
`domain=$(echo ${domaincom/???})` and still can't get it right and can't seem to find the answer.

I want `$step1` to take me to `home/user/public_html/domain`

Any suggestions on how I can fix my syntax?

Comment: `cd` does not produce any output (except when called with `-` as argument).

Comment: `echo "${HOME#/})/public_html/${domaincom#.com}"` ? I assume `$HOME` is set.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem here:

- you don't execute the cd, you evaluate a string that starts with cd. It does nothing. Change the command to 'cd public_html/$domain' to actually change directory.
- the other possible problem is that once the script successfully cd's to the directory you specify (and pwd displays that directory), once it ends it's execution, you are still in the current directory. Because the script starts up a new shell and cd is done in a *that* shell. So you will have to *source* your script (execute it in the current shell). This is the difference between 'myscript' and '. myscript. Don't forget to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this line of code:

```sh
step1=$(cd public_html/$domain)
```

First, `cd` does not produce any output (except when called with `-` as argument but this is not the case). Accordingly, the value of `$step1` will always be the empty string.

Second, and more important, `$()` produces the execution of a command in a sub-shell. This means the shell that runs your script starts a new shell (a clone of itself). This new shell runs `cd ...` and exits. It does not affect the shell that runs the script in any way.

To change the current directory of the shell that runs the script just use `cd` normally:

```sh
cd public_html/$domain
```

If you need to get the current directory **after** you have changed it you can run `pwd` and capture its output:

```sh
step1=$(pwd)
```

#### Extra

```sh
domain=$(echo ${domaincom/.com})
```

There is no need to `echo` a value just to capture its output. You can simply assign the value:

```sh
domain=${domaincom/.com}
```